# How do I install a program on a computer configured with Windows Steady State?

Tags: windows-vista, steadystate

How do I install a program on a computer configured with Windows Steady State such that the protected user can run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember from using it with XP, and depending on how you've got it set up, the steps include:

1. Turning off disk protection
2. Installing program
3. Unlocking the user profile
4. Seting up icons etc. within the user profile
5. Locking the profile
6. Turning on disk protection

There's a lot of options when setting up Steady State. Have you got the [handbook](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F829BB8B-C7A9-426B-A7A4-2B504A6238D2&displaylang=en)?

Comment: I do have the handbook, thanks. I got confused while working with the existing installation. The computer was not restarted in a while, so there were all those profiles of users, one for every time they logged in and I could not figure out which one was the original profile. Once I unlocked the account and put the shortcut into the original profile, everything worked. Thanks!